# Yii2 saving to parent upload file from sub domain

Tags: yii2, subdomain, url-routing, yii2-advanced-app

Good Evening,

I have a sync from facebook using the API to download the images from an album and save to uploads in the root directory.

This was working perfectly but since going production i have had to swap to a subdomain due to shared hosting.

The line for the path i was using is as follows, how would i convert this to save from subdomain.

$path = Yii::getAlias('../uploads/fb/thumb/' . $id . '.jpg');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
__DIR__.'/../uploads/fb/thumb/'

$path = Yii::getAlias(__DIR__.'/../uploads/fb/thumb/' . $id . '.jpg');
```

If a folder is fixed and specified, you can get help from the `Url::to()` or `Url::toRoute` :

```
\yii\helpers\Url::to('path/yourFolder/');
```

Or use Predefined Aliases [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases#predefined-aliases)

like: `@webroot/..`

---

create a URL based on the currently requested route and GET parameters. `>= 2.0.3`

```
echo \yii\helpers\Url::current(); // help?id=1 for example.com/help?id=1
```